# How can I optimize this code? Digit N Powers

Tags: javascript, math

Problem source
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/project-euler/problem-30-digit-n-powers

I am curious as to how I can optimize this code. The goal of the code is to find a sum of all numbers whose digits, when raised to the power n, add to the source number.

````
    ```

    function digitnPowers(n) {
    let newArr = [];
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.pow(9, n) * n; i++) {
      let product = 0;
      let thisVar = i.toString().split("");
      console.log(thisVar);
      for (let j = 0; j < thisVar.length; j++){
        product += Math.pow(thisVar[j], n);
        console.log(product);
      }
      if (product === i) {
        newArr.push(i);
      }
    
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    total += newArr[i];
    console.log(total);
    }
      return total;
    }
       
    ```
````

All of the code, when run, come out with the correct answers:

````
```
digitnPowers(2); = 0
digitnPowers(3); = 1301
digitnPowers(4); = 19316
digitnPowers(5); = 443839
```
````

The console logs are only present to help me learn to solve this problem. My first step in optimization would be to remove those.
My concern is that when I run this function with 5, the code needs to loop nearly 300,000 times, and this function with 4, nearly 27,000. If n were 6, it'd require 3.1million loops. As of now, the code works, but slowly. Any ideas?

Comment: Oftentimes, these problems have one simple and slow solution and one tricky and fast solution. And the latter can usually not be simply derived by modifying the former (by e.g. removing console logs) but requires an entirely different approach. I don't have the answer for this problem. Out of curiosity: How did you find the upper loop bound? I.e., how do you know that the numbers that fulfill the criterion for `n=20` have at most 20 digits?

Comment: Suppose you first compute the n'th powers of all 10 digits. Might that suggest a shortcut? (I don't know if it does, that's just the kind of noodling around you can do to try and solve these problems).